Trying to create a language switch
So I am trying to create a language switch for a website project I'm working on. It includes witching between English, Latvian and Norwegian. I have written a simple switch code in JS to accommodate this function, where it is supposed to hide the language options, within the HTML, and only reveal the selected one.


$('[lang="lv"]').hide();
$('[lang="no"]').hide();

$('#lang-switch').change(function() {
  var lang = $(this).val();
  switch (lang) {
    case 'en':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="en"]').show();
      break;
    case 'lv':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="lv"]').show();
      break;
    case 'no':
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="no"]').show();
      break;
    default:
      $('[lang]').hide();
      $('[lang="en"]').show();
  }
});
[lang="lv"],
[lang="no"] {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="lang-switch">
  <select id="lang-switch">
    <option value="en" onchange="en">EN</option>
    <option value="lv" onchange="lv">LV</option>
    <option value="no" onchange="no">NO</option>
  </select>
</form>



However, after loading the site, where it start off with English, if I select either LV or NO, it will cause all the elements to be styled with Style:display=none;. And I cannot figure out why for the life of me.
I want to make it so that selecting the language from the form, it hides the english navbar and reveals the other language one.

First of remove onchange="*" attributes from <option>s. Then a question: why not use CSS instead of JS? You'll not suffer from the flash of content. Also, have you researched on how to store the selected language to persist after i.e. a page refresh?

You can change language on parent (e.g. body) element some attribute and rest to select by CSS.
To persist information between refreshes - use localStorage.


// Run immediatly
(function () {
  // Will throw error in StackOverflow.
  //let lang = localStorage.getItem('lang');
  let lang = null;

  $('#wrapper').attr('data-lang-main', lang != null ? lang : 'en');
})();

$('#lang-switch').change(function() {
  let lang = $(this).val();

  $('#wrapper').attr('data-lang-main', lang);

  // Will throw error in StackOverflow.
  //localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
});
[data-lang] {
  display: none;
}

#wrapper[data-lang-main="en"] [data-lang="en"] {
  display: initial;
}

#wrapper[data-lang-main="lv"] [data-lang="lv"] {
  display: initial;
}

#wrapper[data-lang-main="no"] [data-lang="no"] {
  display: initial;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="lang-switch">
  <select id="lang-switch">
    <option value="en">EN</option>
    <option value="lv">LV</option>
    <option value="no">NO</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div id="wrapper" data-lang-main="en">
  <span data-lang="en">Phrase EN</span>
  <span data-lang="lv">Phrase LV</span>
  <span data-lang="no">Phrase NO</span>
</div>



